# Sticky Session in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I'm going through some peculiar requirement. In our in-house kubernetes environment some services we pinned (sticky session) to specific node by declaring below values in deployment.yaml

spec:
serviceAccountName: XXXXXX
nodeName: XXXXXXXX

Can i able to provide condition in deployment yaml if node down/ any other issue not able to deploy service in specific node, then it has to move specific node and deploy to serve the requests.

example:- pinned to node1 (service pinned node)
If node1 down it has to deploy in node2.

I google to get some info but not able to get any proper results. Can anyone have done this type of configuration, please suggest me.

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you are looking for, but I think you are looking for NodeAffinity.  Where you can prefer some node, but if that node is not available, it will schedule on a different one.

Comment: yes Leroy that is the real requirement, recently where my service is pinned that node got problem and it went down, due to this specific reason we though to check alternative option it can switch to some other node if node not available

Comment: Please take a closer look at [node affinity concept](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#node-affinity) and decide if it meets your requirements. In your case you may consider a "soft" affinity i.e. `preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution` which will make sure that the scheduler will try to schedule your pod to a particular node, but if it is not available for some reason, it will be still possible to schedule it on a different node.